# ScrollView layout bug when applying Frame modifier

Tags: ios, swiftui

I've stumbled upon the layout issue with ScrollView in SwiftUI.
I think it's a SwiftU bug but I want to double-check with you.

Here's my simple view code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .background(Color.red)
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

And here's how it looks. You can see the "Hello World" is outside scroll view frame. Is that normal? Is there any way to fix it?

[image]

Things are working as expected when I delete `frame(...)` modifier.
[image]

Comment: Vote for bug. the sooner you submit it to Apple the better.

Comment: @Asperi i argee! unfortunately there is o lot of bugs in current release. ... by the way, i use different workaround (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some kind of workaround (might be acceptable in some cases as temporary solution)

Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { gp in
        ScrollView {
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .background(Color.red)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: 300, maxHeight: 300)
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is one of terrible bugs, I suggest next workaround

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .background(Color.red)
        }
        // workaround, please report the bug to Apple !!
        .offset(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}
```

[image]